# need help tracing this reversion method of a binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

this is a method to find the largest number in a binary tree.
the 2 recursion lines above each other are confusing me.
can someone please show me how to trace this code.

```
public int findMax() {
return findMax(root);
}
public static int findMax(Node n) {
if(n == null)
return -1;
int maxLeft = findMax(n.left);
int maxRight = findMax(n.right);
return Math.max(((Integer)n.data).intValue(), Math.max(maxLeft, maxRight));
}
```

Comment: With a debugger.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this relates to `reversion` (and what, exactly,  `reversion` means in this context)? Please try and format/indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

`(1)A
     /   \
    /     \
  (2)B     (5)C
  /   \     /  \
(3)N  (4)N (6)N (7)N`

- A-B-C are ordinary nodes.
- N represents a NULL.

Let's assume we call the function `findMax(A)`:

1. Check if node A is A NULL pointer -> NO, then continue.
2. Find the max value in the left subtree of A which is rooted at B.

   This will call the function `findMax(B)`:

   - Check if node B is a NULL pointer -> NO, then continue.
   - Find the max value in the **left** subtree of B which is rooted at N.

     This will call the function `findMax(NULL)`.
     Since the Node is NULL then -1 will be returned.
   - Now, Find the max value in the **right** subtree of B which is rooted at N.
     Since the Node is NULL then -1 will be returned.
   - The answer for node B is now the maximum of the Left Subtree, Right Subtree and the value of node B.
   - Now, we have computed the maximum value in the left subtree of A rooted at B.
3. Find the max value in the right subtree of A which is rooted at C.

   This will call the function `findMax(C)`:

   - Similar to the steps in part 2, we will end up getting the maximum value in the right subtree of A rooted at C.
4. The answer for node A will be max of its value and the maxima of its two subtrees rooted at B & C.